# How can i customize a dialog box in GMF?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-gmf

[image]

Hi,

I am doing a project in GMF. I want to customize a dialog box with a set of default values under the "Choices" column. This is a dialog box which contains a set of values on the left side (Choices), that can be selected to the right side (Feature), and can be moved up or down. Kindly help me..

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class extends to jface Dialog, implement the methods for configuring the shell and create control where you can create composite with two columns in which 1st column will have your default value column "Choices", you can use tree viewer or table viewer according to your requirement. On the selection of content in tree viewer activate the 2nd column composite. You can even use pagebook, A pagebook is a composite control where only a single control is visible at a time.